# How to update an object but leave some fields the same

Tags: django, django-forms

So I am making an update form and I want to allow the user to update fields he wants to update and leave the rest alone. But django won't let him leave the build_name field alone with no changes because build_name is a primarykey and has to be unique. However it is the object itself that is triggering the fact that the name already exists.

```
def update(request, id):
title = 'Updating Build'
the_name = champBuild.objects.filter(pk=id).values_list('build_name', flat=True)

form  = champBuildUpdateForm(request.POST or None, initial={'build_name': str(the_name)[3:-2]})
if form.is_valid():
    champBuild.objects.filter(pk=id).update(build_name=form.cleaned_data.get('build_name'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/lolBuilds/detail/{}'.format(form.cleaned_data.get('build_name')))
context = {
    'title': title,
    'form': form
}
return render(request, 'lolBuilds/update.html', context)
```

and this is the create.html

```
<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' value='create'/>
</form>
```

This is what happens when I click update without changing the Build name field.

[image]

Comment: Seems to me you have created a ModelForm. But you are using it like a simple Form. So you either need to change your form type, or the way you are using it.

Comment: So with a ModelForm I cannot keep the Build name the same?

Comment: You can, but to validate the form, you will need to pass `instance` keyword parameter instead of `initial`. In instance you will pass actual object of model class i.e. `champBuild.objects.get(pk=id)`.

Comment: So now my line is   
`form  = champBuildUpdateForm(request.POST or None, instance={'build_name': str(the_name)[3:-2]})`  

But now I have a dict missing attribute Meta Error

Comment: Nevermind! Thank you very much!